# ajax call can't retrieve data from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

i am new to ajax.Here i am trying to retrieve data from mysql database.But all i am getting here is an empty array and a notice saying undefined index q on line 2 .Can't figure out what might be the problem behind this.Any help will be appreciated.Here i am using a database which has three column to each row(id,name,age).

***i am having an error .saying i am sending a request to getuser.php.Though my page name is callajax.php.From where this getuser.php coming from?It gives me desired output when i changed the file name to getuser.php.I don't understand.why callajax.php wouldn't work?***

html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function showUser(str) {
    if (str == "") {
        document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
        return;
    } else {
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else {
            // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
                document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }
        xmlhttp.open("GET","callajax.php?q="+str,true);
        xmlhttp.send();

    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="users" onchange="showUser(this.value)">
  <option value="">Select a person:</option>
  <option value="1">al zami rahman</option>
  <option value="4">junayed hasan</option>
  <option value="5">tapos alam</option>

  </select>
</form>
<br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here...</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

callajax.php page:

```
   $m=$_GET['q'];
   $pdo=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=ajax",'root','');
   $conn=$pdo->prepare('SELECT age FROM people WHERE id=?');
   $conn->bindValue(1,$m);
   if($conn->execute()){
      $result=$conn->fetchAll();
      print_r($result);
   }
```

Comment: an empty array would indicate that there are just no results matching your query.

Comment: try first print_r($_GET); What you receive there? Then try to print the query and execute it in mysql client directly. Does it return any rows?

Comment: @bksi i am also getting a notice saying undefined index q on line 2.echoing $_GET returning nothing.

Comment: then your ajax call doesn't fill $_GET['q']. What do you see when print_r($_GET); ?

Comment: You can check your php file using the link in your browser. http://yourserver/callajax.php?q=1 for example

Comment: check your table name and column name in your database!!

Comment: i checked .they are ok !

Comment: i am having an error .saying i am sending a request to getuser.php.Though my page name is ajaxcall.php.From where this getuser.php coming from?It gives me desired output when i changed the file name to getuser.php.I don't understand.why callajax.php wouldn't work?

Comment: Have you used getuser.php before. Then you may need to clear your browser cache /refresh the whole page every time you change your file name.

Comment: I checked your code its is perfectly calling callajax.php. So i don't think problem with your code